# How valuable is academic publishing for a data science career?

Tags: professional-development

I've been working an analyst job in retail for a few months that is really more of a data science role. My background is in applied economics, and I have a master's in the field. I've recently been offered the chance to coauthor a paper in economics with some associates from when I was in grad school. This would be done outside of my other job. It's possible (likely?) that the paper would be published in an A ranked journal (ie. ranked probably top 30-40) in economics.

Are publications like this considered especially valuable in the private sector and more specifically, in a data science career path? Would a publication be an eye-catcher on a resume? Would it be a big mistake to turn it down? For what it's worth, the paper would have nothing to do with retail or business more generally.

I'm trying to figure out if it makes sense to spend the time on this, or if I'd be better off learning other skills for my current job. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace :) please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to start to familiarize yourself with this stack. Also, I posted an answer for you to consider, hope it helps, cheers and again, welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are publications like this considered especially valuable in the private sector and more specifically, in a data science career path?

Depends on the specifics but it certainly doesn't harm. In most cases it would be "moderately valuable", primarily because it shows

1. You have enough scientific rigor and skills to get into a peer reviewed journal.
2. You have the stamina and commitment to see it through to a successful end.

The topic itself is rarely valuable unless it lines up exactly with what the company needs right now, which is unlikely.

> Would a publication be an eye-catcher on a resume?

It's certainly a decent differentiator which most other applicants won't have. Again, it can't harm. In most cases it will have to some amount.

> Would it be a big mistake to turn it down?

Impossible to tell. I think it will increase your chances of success but no one knows whether it will make a really significant difference for your next job.

Answer (score 1):

> Are publications like this considered especially valuable in the private sector and more specifically, in a data science career path? Would a publication be an eye-catcher on a resume? Would it be a big mistake to turn it down?

It's a bit hard to tell. However, a publication generally speaking is a positive thing, and having one (or more) could definitely be beneficial or at least "eye-catcher" as you say.

I said "hard to tell", because this would depend on the specific eye you what to catch ;) ... perhaps for some recruiters it would be very interesting, for others be ok, and perhaps for others irrelevant...

If the publication has nothing to do with where you are applying, then the relevance would be less (or none), and perhaps come up as you including it as a filler... Remember that it's recommended to tailor your resume for the role you are applying, so if the job you seek is related to the paper or topics covered in the publication then surely would be worth including it.

> I'm trying to figure out if it makes sense to spend the time on this, or if I'd be better off learning other skills for my current job

This is something that eventually boils down to what you want in your life and career, so be sure to give it a good thought.

My two cents I can say on this is that I see you mentioned *learning other skills for my current job*... do you plan to be on your current job forever? Do you see yourself on this job (hopefully promoted) in the short, mid and long term? What if you eventually leave this job, would the publication have been worth it then?

These are some questions you could reflect on to make a choice.

Also, make sure that the time you would invest in the publication does not interfere with your current responsibilities in your job. Also make sure that there is no NDA or other thing that could prevent you from engaging in activities like this (you mentioned that the paper would have nothing to do with business/retail, so I *guess* it would be fine, although it's better to be completely sure).

Answer (score 1):

This is borderline VTC for me - as the answer really does heavily depend on how much weight the reviewer of your CV puts on it.

I, myself, am not a big fan of Academia (in it's current form) and so it would be little more than a curiosity.

However, another reviewer who might place a lot more stock in Academia might see that and decide to move forward with the application.

The real key for me though is how important the publication turned out to be. A Major publication that was cited multiple times by multiple people could be a crowning achievement on a CV. However, if it doesn't have any citations, it's probably not going to garner much more than a 'Oh, that's interesting'

Comment: VTC - What's one of those in this context?

Comment: @SimonB VTC = Vote To Close the question